# Apache POI - how do you give excel the FilePath as a "parameter" to enable save instead of Save As?

Tags: java, file-io, apache-poi

i think my case is pretty unique, ive been looking all over but i didn't find anything.

my program as it is, makes a customer object, writes it to an excel file with the customer attributs, after this you can right-click the customer and open up it's excel file, but my functionality requirements demand that the customer can then edit manually in the excel workbook to finish up whatever information i didn't have, and i want to save this manually added information, but  i get stuck at the SaveScreen in excel - because i can't save excel w/o adding a file location.

My research let me to the fact, that it's possible to edit the excel functionality through the workbook methods somehow. And im imaging a solution where i make excel understand where the file is comeing from w/o useing "save as" - but doing it automatically.

Thanks alot .

---

yeah ive might've not made my self entirely clear.

the Customer in this case is a "person" - whom is reflected as a object named Customer inside of the system.

when i say "clicked on customer" - i refer to a JTable filled with customer objects.

i was just trying to add a little context, but i see now that it was rather confuseing.

basically what it boils down to, is me trying to save a excel workbook after the user(the guy who uses the system) have edited it manually, but since i opened the workbook through java, excel cannot find the path of the file which normally enables the "save" option.  which means that the user has to pick a new location to save into.

i would like to be able tell excel somehow - where the file came from - through java.

i open the file useing the class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html -

Comment: what do you mean customer object ? a folder ?

Comment: i got confuse in your way saying "customer", [customer](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer‎) is a person!